# Background image lost when scroll with browser window resize. Need help to fix

Tags: css

I have a weird problem.  The background image (black stripes) in the main container breaks up when the browser window is resized smaller and the user/viewer scrolls up and down (in Safari).  The stripes stop stretching down 100%.

```
 #mother   {width:   100%; min-height: 100%;height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: url('/img/bg.png') repeat-y center;}
```

[link text](http://www.thepaperboutique.biz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way of directly changing this behaviour myself. Firefox is the same, I think, at least horizontally.

Does it make any difference if you apply the background image to an element that contains #mother? Depending on your page, perhaps you could apply it to the body.

Answer (score 1):

The way to change this horizontally is to set a min-width declaration on the div. Mid-width 100% doesn't work, you need a pixel value.

I don't seem able to duplicate your problem in Safari (or any other browser) vertically - the stripes don't reach the bottom of the page even on first load.

Answer (score 1):

Quite Tricky :)

```
body { display: table; width:100%}
```